# how to set album privacy settings using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any way to change the Facebook album privacy settings with `graph api`?
I'm trying to find out, but all I could found is how to get the privacy settings using `fql`, but not to set.

I'm creating the album as follow

```
$postdata = http_build_query(array(
          'name' => $album_name,
          'message' => $album_description
            )
          );

  $opts = array('http' =>
         array(
          'method'=> 'POST',
          'header'=>
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => $postdata
          )
         ) $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
 $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));
         $albumid = $result->id;
```

Now if I add `privacy=>"value"`, it gives `$albumid=null`.
I'm not sure where I need to add privacy parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The document of creating an album is put in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums

Privacy setting is a json-style string. So you could create an array() and use json_encode() to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an album, you can send these parameters in post request.

```
name, message, location and privacy.
```

Value of privacy field can be set like this,

```
 privacy={value: "CUSTOM"} (send this as post parameter)
```

The value field may specify one of the following strings:

```
EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM .
```

As facebook docs sucks, there's no mention about it on `albums object` page.

However, you can read it on [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object.

**Edit:**  (after comments)

In php sdk you can do something like this,

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('me/albums', 'POST',
                                           array(
                                              'privacy' => '{value: "CUSTOM"}',
                                              'location' => 'India'
                                         ));
```

Comment: Thank you Jashwant. But could you explain more,

Comment: Which sdk or method are you trying ?

Answer (score -1):

with php sdk it is also possible as php style @kaur

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/albums/', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => 'Picture uploaded',
                     'location' => 'Goran',
                     'privacy'=> array('value'=>'EVERYONE'),    //'privacy'=> '{value: "EVERYONE"}', //worked too!! SELF, ALL_FRIENDS, EVERYONE
                                         )
                                      );
```